# Prononciation of "en", "an", "in", "un" and "ain"

Tags: prononciation, voyelles

I'm a totally beginner in French. For some reason I can't figure out the pronunciation rules. Especially for the vowels. It's almost as confusing as Korean language :(
To me "en" and "an" sound the same? like the English /a/??
"in" and "ain" sound the same? I can't find a English similar vowels… maybe there's none?
and "un" ?

Anyone has some easy tips to remember?